# DSaaS Python Script to Search for Global Rule by HASH

Tags: python, deepsecurity

Would like to use Python to search the DSaaS global rules to see if a certain HASH/SHA256 is in the global rule set.

Code below.  How do I get the SHA256 value (hash256) in the search_filter object?

```
    hash256 = str(input("Pleas enter the hash that you would like to search: "))
    print(hash256)

    try:
        search_filter = deepsecurity.SearchFilter()

        api_response = api_instance.search_global_rules(api_version, search_filter=search_filter)
        pprint(api_response)
    except ApiException as e:
        print("An exception occurred when calling GlobalRulesApi.search_global_rules: %s\n" % e)
```

Not getting the search to work by HASH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to perform a search on the Application Control Global Rules you will need to first create a `SearchCriteria` as follows

```py
# Create SearchCriteria
searchCriteria = deepsecurity.SearchCriteria(
    field_name='sha256',
    string_test='equal',
    string_value=hash256
)
```

and then add it to your `SearchFilter` object

```py
search_filter = deepsecurity.SearchFilter(search_criteria=searchCriteria)
```

Overall your code will be as follows

```py
hash256 = str(input("Please enter the hash that you would like to search: "))
print(hash256)

# Create SearchCriteria
searchCriteria = deepsecurity.SearchCriteria(
    field_name='sha256',
    string_test='equal',
    string_value=hash256
)

# Add SearchCriteria to SearchFilter
search_filter = deepsecurity.SearchFilter(search_criteria=searchCriteria)

try:
    api_response = api_instance.search_global_rules(api_version, search_filter=search_filter)
    pprint(api_response)
except ApiException as e:
    print("An exception occurred when calling GlobalRulesApi.search_global_rules: %s\n" % e)
```

Check out this [guide](https://automation.deepsecurity.trendmicro.com/article/12_5/how-to-search?platform=dsaas) for advanced searches, such as using wildcards and more.

P.S. I work for Trend Micro on the Deep Security team.

Comment: Thank you again...works great!  I have python script that has these functions.

Welcome to Deep Security Security Automation tool for Global Rule Hash Files

Following below the actions allowed today from this tool:

1 - Add File Hash from Input File
2 - Add Single File Hash/Description
3 - Search for Single Hash
4 - Search for Single Description
5 - Delete File Hash by ID (use #5 first)
6 - List All File Hash to Screen
7 - Export All File Hash to File
8 - Close the session